# Install gRPC for PHP

Tags: php, grpc

I want to install gRPC for PHP 7.3. I followed [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc#using-pecl) documentation.

I use `ubuntu 16.04`, `Nginx`

I install:

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf zlib1g-dev php-dev php-pear
sudo pecl install grpc
```

But I am getting this error:

> No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/grpc"
>
> install failed

I don't know what is wrong.

It is `php -v`

```
PHP 7.3.22-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Sep  9 2020 06:46:12) ( NTS )   
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.22, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies with Zend OPcache v7.3.22-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Please, help me.

Comment: what is your platform aka processor?

Comment: sorry, I updated my question. Pls check one more time

Comment: still no answer is it ARM or x64?

Comment: sorry, it is x64

Comment: try using `sudo pecl install grpc-1.32.0`

Comment: https://ibb.co/q5cxFdL

see, same error

Comment: does it take long time? because I have noticed that pecl repo has problems right now, and check your pecl version if it's 1.4.0+

Comment: PEAR Version: 1.10.8. Actually, I used to install it. But I couldn't this time.

Comment: Ok so there is probably a problem with repo, you can try 2 things... 1. use `gRPC` instead of `grpc`, it's a proper name, but server has a redirection, so `sudo pecl install gRPC`, 2. Install `lynx` and check if you can `lynx http://pecl.php.net/package/grpc` and `lynx https://pecl.php.net/package/grpc`, if not, the server is down and you just have to wait so they would fix the connection problems, if not, I don't know ... maybe someone else can help you :) Could be that it's because of all those debianisho-ubuntu mods of PHP are the problem.

Comment: I tried `sudo pecl install gRPC`. Same error, let me try `lynx`

Comment: I think I found a problem. Most probably, the server, that I am using, blocked pecl.php.net. I cannot ping to pecl.php.net

Comment: Yupp, should return pings... `PING pecl.php.net (104.236.228.160) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from pecl.php.net (104.236.228.160): icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=90.1 ms`

Comment: @FlashThunder My server provider blocked pecl.php.net website. I couldn't ping it. Are there any alternatives for pecl? Or how can I install a VPN for my server? Or can I copy this gRPC package from another server that I already have installed? Pls help if you have an idea

Comment: https://www.gosquared.com/blog/howto-installing-pecl-extensions-on-a-mediatemple-dv-server

Comment: I'm using a Dockerfile based on a ubuntu/debian image, I needed to `apt install ca-certificates` and run `pecl channel-update pecl.php.net` before `pecl install grpc`